# Error on importing CSV to Magento

Tags: sql, magento, csv, upload

I'm uploading a CSV. The first 200 products upload okay, but fail after that. I've tried deleting the first 210 in the csv, and uploading again, but just continually shows this error (dbname removed).

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`##databasename##`.`mg_catalog_product_entity_varchar`, CONSTRAINT `FK_mg_CAT_PRD_ENTT_VCHR_ENTT_ID_mg_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `mg_catalog_product_entity` (`)
```

Any ideas?

C

Comment: foreign key constraint is failing.. Are you using custom script to execute this?

Comment: Hi @KalpeshMehta - nope, I'm using the built in Magento import function, with a UTF8 CSV.

I have no duplicate SKUs, and not using any child rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, turns out that my UTF8 encoding hadn't worked. Sorted now.
Trick is to change settings under Web Options in Excel.

**Scratch that - stopped working again! Very weird.**

Now getting the message:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`##dbname##`.`mg_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`, CONSTRAINT `FK_mg_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_ATTR_ID_mg_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `mg_eav_attribute` (`a)
```

Any thoughts?